# spring rabbitmq client closes channel with error "Channel shutdown: connection error"

Tags: java, spring, docker, rabbitmq

I am running a spring java application in a docker container which connects to rabbitMQ server running on other docker container.

I observed that when my application thread doing some long processing, in the middle of processing i am getting the following error messages from rabbitMQ on stdout.

`ERROR CachingConnectionFactory:281 - Channel shutdown: connection error`

And after finishing of long processing by my process, getting the following heartbeat missing exception:

```
Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.checkShutdown(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:312)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:367)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1016)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1005)
...

Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.MissedHeartbeatException: Heartbeat missing with heartbeat = 60 seconds
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleSocketTimeout(AMQConnection.java:597)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$600(AMQConnection.java:65)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:560)
        ... 1 more
2016-04-11 05:59:08 INFO  SimpleMessageListenerContainer:1234 - Restarting Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-YW4oYetZsWNj12tXt-nX7g=dynamicModeling.queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@172.17.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

rabbitMQ server side log errors are as below:

```
=WARNING REPORT==== 11-Apr-2016::05:48:22 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.942.0> (172.17.0.6:36993 -> 172.17.0.1:5672):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**:

The following Docker commands used:

rabbitMQ server : 
docker run -d --name rabbitmq -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitMQImage

my app container: docker run -d --name myAPP --link rabbitmq:rabbitmq myImage

Comment: Attach your docker run commands/configs, pls

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?